# re-set gl.viewport() does not work

Tags: webgl

When I resize my four canvases (actual width and height, not just CSS, to adapt to screen ratio when going fullscreen), the canvas which uses webgl does not update. Though I call

```
gl.viewport( 0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight );
```

it stays with original ratio, and so it is offset from the other canvas.

What am I missing ?

The only info I could find on the internet is to update my matrix too, but I do not use any matrix, I just use a texture on two triangles.

creation code :

```
gl.viewport(0, 0, game.w, game.h);

gl.vertexShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-vertex-shader");
gl.fragmentShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-fragment-shader");
gl.program = createProgram(gl, [gl.vertexShader, gl.fragmentShader]);
gl.useProgram( gl.program);

gl.positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation( gl.program, "a_position");
gl.texCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation( gl.program, "a_texCoord");

gl.texCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.texCoordBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( gl.texCoordLocation );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( gl.texCoordLocation , 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.posBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , gl.posBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER , new Float32Array([
        0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( gl.positionLocation );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( gl.positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );

gl.resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation( gl.program, "u_resolution" );
webglalpha = gl.getUniformLocation( gl.program, "alpha" );
```

Comment: can you post a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: @gman: I will try.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes their value is the correct new resolution of the game though. I resize the canvases. The purpose is to adapt to the ratio of the window or the fullscreen, more height and less width for 4/3 and 3/2 screens, more width and less height for 16/9 and 18/9 screens.

Comment: You should really **not** put properties on the WebGL context like that. It's bad practice. `gl.program`, `gl.texCoordLocation`, `gl.posBuffer`, `gl.texCoordBuffer`, `gl.resolutionLocation` are not a WebGL things. It's just your code adding a random properties to the WebGL context. It's extremely confusing and not remotely scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I found out by myself, the resolution uniform has to be updated too :

```
gl.uniform2f( gl.resolutionLocation , game.width , game.height );
```